# errors in main_activity.java file

Tags: java, android, android-activity

> cannot find symbol class intent, cannot find...Activity2.class, cannot find...Activity-main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) { 
            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    NewActivity2.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

all the imports precede the above code like import widget button, etc.

Comment: Do you have another activity called `NewActivity2`?

Comment: Could you show the import for NewActivity2?
Also, please show the code of NewActivity2 and activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Open your Manifest and check if there are entries like these:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity android:name=".NewActivity2" />
```

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".NewActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve.MainActivity" />
                </activity>

Comment: but get message when trying to compile cannot find symbol class intent, NewActivity2, or variable Activity_main  I want to say up-front thank you so much for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Overriding method should call super, so it should be:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

and make sure that your NewActivity2 is registered in manifest.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. Apears may be an issue with the manifest? the latter part of my manifest now looks like this <activity android:name=".NewActivity2" android:label="@string/title_activity_main2" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve.MainActivity" /> </activity>